# Firebase collection document key name starting with 'is_' removed 'is' from key name

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store a sub collection in firestore database like below:

```
var storiesCollRef= mFirestore.collection("groups").document(documentID.toString()).collection("stories")
    var stories = Stories(
                is_attachement = if(imageList.isNotEmpty()) 1 else 0,
                numComments = 0,
                numLaughs = 0,
                original_image = firebaseImagesPath,
                storyText = edtStoryText.text.toString(),
                thumb_image = firebaseImagesPath,
                timestamp = Timestamp.now(),
                userName = PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(activity!!, PrefUtils.SIGNUP_FAMILY_TITLE, "").toString(),
                userid = PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(activity!!, PrefUtils.SIGNUP_USER_EMAIL, "").toString()
    )
    storiesCollRef.add(stories).addOnCompleteListener{task ->
        Log.d("story created", task.result?.id)
        if(task.isSuccessful){
            progressDialog?.dismiss()
            //open dashboard
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Model class

```
data class Stories(
val is_attachement: Int? = 0,
val numComments: Int? = 0,
var numLaughs: Int? = 0,
val original_image: ArrayList<String>? = null,
val storyText: String? = "",
val thumb_image: ArrayList<String>? = null,
val timestamp: Timestamp? = Timestamp.now(),
val userName: String? = "",
val userid: String? = "",
val docID: String? = ""){}
```

It stores all the data perfectly but it changes the name of 'is_attachement' field to ' *attachement'. It also does the same for other fields starting with 'is*' like 'is_migrate' and 'is_self_created' is other collection documents.

[image: like this image]

[image: and this image]

Anybody has any solution, please let me know thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default serialization scheme for POJO type objects in JVM based languages (such as both Kotlin and Java) removes the "is" from the name of a member to assign a property name.  If you don't want this default behavior, you should annotate the properties with [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) to give it a specific name.

I will say, however, that using underscores in Kotlin property names is not correct Kotlin style.  You should be using camel case instead.  Also, for boolean type properties, they should be Bool instead of Int.

See also: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-firestore/firestore-change-kotlin-pojo-property-name-mapping/

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much. This solved my problem..
I solved it from the attached link. I did it like this: @JvmField @PropertyName("is_attachement")